# NodeJS(express) How would i finish this .js file and .ejs file to query the objectiD within my browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

All i want to achieve is querying an objectID from my mongoDB into my nodeJS then retrieving it in my local host via
http://localhost:3000/objectSearch?objectid=

Ive google everything and i just cannot figure it out. If someone would finish the example so i can see how it works, thanks ! :D

**`**objectSearch.js**`**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var objectID = require('mongodb')
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/WishList';


    router.get("/", function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("unable to connect to server", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Connect to server");
            var collection = db.collection('orders');
            var _id = req.query.id
            collection.findOne({_id: mongodb.ObjectID(_id)}, function (err, result) {
                if (err || !result) {
                    res.render('error', {error: "No records found with that id"});
                } else {
                    res.render(
                        'objectSearch',
                        {
                            objectSearch: result,
                            title: result
                        })
                }
            })
        }
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

**ObjectSearch.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%=objectSearch.name.f %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter on the url it's not `id`, but `objectid`, so your line of code should be:

```
req.query.objectid
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll change that tomorrow and see what else is needed to complete it. (I presume it's not finished)

Comment: Check if your query is retuning correctly, before sending to the view.

Comment: I will do, I'll use console.log. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the answer is correct, please choose as the best answer, please :)

You are welcome! :)